# Given groups G, H, when can one find generators $F_G$ of $G$ such that $\text{Hom}_{group}(G,H)=\text{Hom}_{set}(F_G,H).$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given groups $G,H,$ when can one find generators $F_G$ of $G$ such that $$\text{Hom}(G,H)=\text{Hom}(F_G,H),$$ where on the left side we are taking group homomorphisms and on the right we are taking set-theoretic functions (equivalently, we can take $F_G$ to be the free group and consider group morphisms). For example, if $G$ is free on $F_G$ then this is true for any $H.$ Similarly, if $G$ is free abelian on $F_G$ then this is true (at least) if $H$ is abelian. For a more nontrivial example one can take $G$ to be the fundamental group of a surface with its usual generators and let $H$ be abelian. I'm assuming it isn't always true, but I don't know of an example (edit: I think the number of morphisms must be a power of $|H|$).

Comment: You're correct to think that it's not always true. For example, it's not true when $G$ is free abelian of rank $2$ and $H$ is the symmetric group $S_3$, as there are $18$ homomorphisms from $G$ to $H$, and $18$ is not a power of $|H|=6$ .

Comment: Another counterexample: $G = C_3$, $H = C_2$.

Comment: This is a sidenote, but a group may not have any minimal generating set.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Yes, that's a much easier example! (Where's the embarrassed face emoji?)

Answer (score 1):

The reason the surface group example works is that the abelianization $G^\mathrm{ab}$ is free abelian.

Here is a bunch of mumbo jumbo that may not help much or may at least give you some buzzwords. In general (and more generally than you ask for), suppose $G = \langle S \rangle$ and we want
$$\mathrm{Hom}(G, H) = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Set}}(S, H) \qquad\qquad (*)$$
for all $H \in \mathcal H$ for some class of groups $\mathcal H$. Let $F = F_\omega$ be a free group with a countably infinite collection of variables $\{x_1, x_2, \dots\}$ and let  $V \trianglelefteq F$ be the verbal subgroup consisting of all words $w \in F$ that are killed by any homomorphism $F \to H \in \mathcal H$ ("laws for $\mathcal H$"). For any group $G$, there is a fully invariant subgroup $V(G) \trianglelefteq G$ given as $$V(G) = \{f(w) : w \in V, f \in \mathrm{Hom}(F,G)\} = \{w(x_1,x_2, \dots) : x_1, x_2, \ldots \in G\}.$$ The *variety* $\mathcal V$ generated by $\mathcal H$ is the class of all groups $G$ such that $V(G) = 1$. The largest quotient of any group $G$ lying in $\mathcal V$ is $G / V(G)$. A group $G$ is $\mathcal V$-*free* with basis $S \subset G$ if $G \in \mathcal V$ and $(*)$ holds for every $H \in\mathcal V$; equivalently $G \cong F_S / V(F_S)$ where $F_S$ is the (absolutely) free group with basis $S$. Now in general $(*)$ holds (for $G$ not necessarily in $\mathcal V$) for all $H \in \mathcal V$ if and only if $G / V(G)$ is $\mathcal V$-free.

Last question: If $(*)$ holds for all $H \in \mathcal H$ does it necessarily hold for all $H \in \mathcal V$? The answer is yes. Consider some map $f : S \to H \in \mathcal V$. There is a unique extension $\tilde f : F_S \to H$. Consider also the natural map $q : F_S \to G$. If $w \in \ker(q)$ then $w$ must be a law for $\mathcal H$, so $w \in V(F_S)$, and since $H \in \mathcal V$ it follows that $w \in \ker(\tilde f)$. Therefore $\ker(q) \le \ker(\tilde f)$ and it follows that $\tilde f$ factors through $q$, which means that $f : S \to H$ extends to a homomorphism $G \to H$.